Compiling import std; with CMake
I'm trying to use C++ modules on a new project.
import std;

int main(){
    std::print("Hello, world!");
}

should compile under C++23.
The documentation of CMake suggests that if you use CMake 3.28+, Clang 18+ and libc++, this can be compiled in practice.
I've managed to install on ubuntu (wsl) CMake 3.30 and Clang 19. Both appear to work as expected. However, I have not found sufficient documentation about how to install libc++, which appears not to be installed but appears to be required for import std to work. I tried following this post but apparently the repository has moved? The docs on the libc++ website had a similar issue. Also, if there's an easier way to get that code to compile with CMake, I would accept that as well.
